# How to disabled zoom for one node? Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Cannot possible disable zoom for node.

I searched in docs all words zoom and cannot found this opportunities.

I want set on some nodes property like `disabledZoom` or maybe it will be setting zoom for some nodes.

Comment: Hi @Pegos, can you please provide us with your code? With a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), more people are willing to answer your question :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search answer and found only one decision. Cytoscape cannot disable one node for zoom. I created example with manual control zooming on the element.

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sky-m5mze

Comment: @stephan-t can you look my solution and maybe you have idea how create better?